# How to read long values from ECU via CAPL

Tags: vector, capl, canoe

I was able to lay hand on ECU from which I would like to read VIN value via CAPL. But I'm able to get response just in single frame not consecutive frame. I'm connected to ECU via CAN.

So how it is possible to read long values from ECU?
I also know, that this ECU sends periodically some messages, so how it is possible to read them in real time, when I know IDs?

```
variables
{
  message 0x123 Request;
  message 0x124 Response;
}

on key 'v'
{
     Request.DLC = 8;
     Request.byte(0) = 0x03;
     Request.byte(1) = 0x22;
     Request.byte(2) = 0xXX;    //command for reading VIN
     Request.byte(3) = 0xYY;    //command for reading VIN
     Request.byte(4) = 0x00;
     Request.byte(5) = 0x00;
     Request.byte(6) = 0x00;
     Request.byte(7) = 0x00;
     output(Request);
}
```

In trace I can see postive response, but just single frame. And I definetelly know, that VIN is longer then that.

```
03 22 XX YY 00 00 00 00
03 62 XX YY 12 34 56 78
```

I read some materials from vector (OSEK_TP, etc.), but I'm not able to apply them, because I'm new to capl.

Comment: Could you please show a screenshot or similar of the trace window? `03 62 XX YY 12 34 56 78` does not look correct. `03` as the first byte, means a single frame with 3 bytes payload, which makes no sense as a response to you request (it would mean that no data is transferred)

Answer (score -2):

It seems the DID in your Software defined to send VIN in 4Bytes.
the Diagnostic service $22 XX YY 
response with 03 62 XX YY 12 34 56 78
62 is a positive response on service 22 which is SF (single frame)
for DID XX YY and following with VIN 12 34 56 78 which mean your defined supported DID provide 4Bytes of data for VIN.
that's mean your diagnostic response is proper.

otherwise, if the defined service DID response need extend frame it will response with 03 09 62 XX YY 12 34 56 78 (09 is ISO-TP number of Bytes it want to transfer, 9 in hex) 
and wait Tester to send control flow 30 00 00 00
then it will start sending consecutive frame 21 9A BC DE 00 00 00 00

assume full VIN is 12 34 56 78 9A BC DE


second question is to get full VIN from CAN message which is a good idea.
you can program like

```
variable
{
 message CAN1.0x501 msg_K;
 byte VIN[7]; //assume VIN14
 int i;
}
on message CAN1.0x501 //CAN CH1, CAN ID 0x501 sending full VIN
{
 for(i=0; i<8, i++)
 {
  VIN[i]=msg_K.byte(i);
 }
}
```